# Render event in Page Life Cycle

Tags: asp.net

I have a following files in my project file.

1. User Control
2. Content Page
3. Site Master

I was checking the page life cycle for `Render` event. `Render` event is being executed in following order.

1. Content Page
2. Master Page
3. User Control

Obviously, It is predefined.

**Question** is, why the content page then Master Page and finally User Control?

I mean how the complete Html is being merged to sent to Browser? Shouldn't it contain Master Page first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render is not an event. It is a method called to generate the output to send to the client.
Render renders itself and its children.

The order is 
Render
RenderChildren

As can clearly be seen in the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

In your control hierarchy, page is the parent. MasterPage is a child of the Page control. Depending on where you have placed your user control, it will be a child of either the Page or MasterPage.

If you create a custom control, you typically override this method to output the control's markup

Each control receives a `HtmlTextWriter` from its parent and writes its output to this writer. The final output received by the client is the output written by control and all its children to writer.

Since the page has to start this process, its Render has to be called first.